# Making a blog in Moodle 2.3 public, viewable to the whole world

Tags: moodle

I am using Moodle 2.3 and want to make blog posts viewable to the whole world or public i.e without having to login or go to a particular course. I think in previous versions of moodle you had the option to make blog posts viewable to yourself, to site users or whole world. I don't seem to have the 'whole world' option when I create a blog post. Has this been removed in 2.3 or does it need to be enabled somewhere else?

Also is it possible to display a list of recent blog posts either as a block on the left/right or inside the home page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. You have to change the blog visibility option in site admin to "The world can see entries set to be world-accessible". By default it's set to "All site users can see all blog entries"

The setting is at `http://your-moodle.com/admin/settings.php?section=blog`

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I was off this for a while. Thanks for your answer kevtufc, worked perfectly!

What I need to do next is display the latest blog posts on the home page or as a block on the left/right. I couldn't find anything that will allow me to do this. Is there an easy way to do this in Moodle? Or do I have to install some sort of extension? Thanks again.